# JAVA Find the biggest in difference pair from text file

Tags: java

Need help with this problem, how can I read in this file line by line, compute each differences by pair and output the pair  with the biggest difference?

Input text file format:

```
157 901
715 322
51 421
85 128
167 292
6 45
89 1787
84 217
560 128
37 1320
```

Comment: Have you ever written any Java code?  What about dealing with text files?

Comment: You could read in each number from the file using `nextInt()` or similar. Compute the difference and compare to line + 1.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Use Filereader and scanner to read each line.  store them in variable, computer difference, put the diff in list and print the largest one.

Comment: Is it the first integer - second?  or second - first?

Comment: @3kings abs(first-second)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So here is something to help you out

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Compute
{

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner scan = new Scanner("C:/path to file");
    int biggest = 0, num1 = 0, num2 = 0, current1, current2;
    while(scan.hasNextInt())
    {
        current1 = scan.nextInt();
        current2 = scan.nextInt();
        if((Math.abs(current1-current2)) > biggest)   //current1 - current2?  or current2 - current1?  You decide
        {
            biggest = Math.abs(current1-current2);  //if you change that also change this
            num1 = current1;
            num2 = current2;
        }
    }

    System.out.println("The pair with the biggest difference is: "+num1+" and "+num2+". Their difference is: "+biggest);
    scan.close();
}

}
```